# Bad request #400 when accessing jquery post ajax in Yii2

Tags: php, jquery, post, yii2

I have been struggling with this bad request error using jquery post. Here's my code:

```
var bookingId = 123;
$.post('<?=Url::base(true)?>/site/requestedc', {'booking_id': bookingId}, function(response){
    alert(response);
}, 'json');
```

Server side is using Yii2:

```
public function actionRequestedc()
{
    echo json_encode("asd");
    die();
}
```

It's simple, but always return Bad Request #400. Can anyone help?

Comment: `requestedc` is not equivalent to `actionRequestedc`

Comment: @Anant-Alivetodie Actually, it is. Route `site/requestedc` by default points to method `actionRequestedc()` in `SiteController` because of Yii2 conventions.

Comment: Most likely the issue is missing CSRF token in POST request. See https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/security-best-practices#avoiding-csrf for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass csrf-token in ajax request.

```
var csrfToken = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content");
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: path,
    dataType: 'json',
    headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN':csrfToken},
    data: 'parameter='+parameter_value,
    success: function (data) {
        success code here
    }
});
```